# WinForms: navigate TreeView in BackgroundWorker thread

Tags: c#, treeview, backgroundworker

I have a simple WinForms application with TreeView control.
I am trying to create ExpandAll function. It calls gets selected node and run recursive function

```
private void expandNode2(TreeNode tn)
{
    if (tn == null) return;

    tn.TreeView.BeginUpdate();
    Application.DoEvents();
    tn.Expand();
    tn.TreeView.EndUpdate();
     foreach (TreeNode tnChild in tn.Nodes)
    {
        expandNode2(tnChild);
    }
 }
```

If tree is large the form is frozen. How to expand the tree in backgroundworker thread?  When I call this function I receive the cross-thread error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the main thread owns the treeView you would need to call invoke to update the tree.  But that would put the expansion of the nodes back on the the main thread which would lock your UI.

You can clone you root node though and pass that to the background worker(bw)
expand that node and its children then pass it back and set your root = to the bw result (which can be done in the bw completed method).  That will move all the expansion to the bw but may be expensive resource wise since we have to clone your nodes first

```
    private void btnExpandR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        TreeNode tempnode = treeView.Nodes[0].Clone() as TreeNode;
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += NodeCopy;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(tempnode);
    }

    private void NodeCopy(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        treeView.Nodes[0] = e.Result as TreeNode;
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode tempNode = e.Argument as TreeNode;
        Exp(tempNode);
        e.Result = tempNode;
    }

    private void Exp(TreeNode tn)
    {
        tn.Expand();

        foreach(TreeNode t in tn.Nodes)
        {
            if(t.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                exp(t);
            }
        }
    }
```

You could also just expand with

```
    private void Exp(TreeNode tn)
    {
        tn.ExpandAll();
    }
```

Comment: It seems good, I will try it, thanks. I understand that I can use expandall, but here is another idea: the tree fills from db via WCF. I want to have test app to create loading for WCF and db. I click button and tree is expanding level by level. This way I can run N forms in app or N applications and they will create automatic loading.

Comment: In this case user sees the tree expanded, but does not see the progress, expanding step by step.

Comment: In that case I think you are going about this a bit backwards.  Instead of building the tree then trying to expand it layer by layer.  Why not build the tree with expanded nodes as you load the nodes from the db?  As soon as I tried to copy nodes deeper in than treeView.Nodes[0]  using treeview.Nodes.Find the tree stopped expanding.  The only way I could get it to expand one node at a time from a already populated tree is to remove the node in the bw completed and re add the expanded copy of that node.

Comment: You could also move a control that holds the tree to a separate thread completely so you can do what you want to it without worrying about cross thread issues.  Its a little more complicated than a bw to set up but I think the over all complexity would be lower.

Comment: I am developing small app for the load testing, i.e. it will collapse the tree then step by step expanding, collapse again etc etc. Number of levels to expand and number of iterations are input parameters to simulate lower or higher loading.

Comment: It is good idea. How I can move tree to separate thread? Now TreeView is on main Form.